# PHP contact form change HTML entity codes into ASCII characters

Tags: php, html, utf-8, ascii

I have a php form with `<meta charset="utf-8" />` (I also tried with `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />` which give me the same result)

When I test my form with the characters `"` and `'`, the email I receive transform those characters into their ASCII characters :

```
Subject: \"\'   

Message: \&#34;\&#39;

Sent by: \&#34;\&#39;
```

(Somehow, the subject field only adds a `\` before the characters)

I have also noticed that anything in between `<` and `>` are stripped out in `$formAuthor`  and `$formContent` but not in  `$formSubject`

Also if the from is submitted with a error in the captcha, the form keep in memory what was written in the field but anything after " in the `$formAuthor`  and `$formSubject` is stripped out but not in `$formContent` (it's weird because it does follow the same logic than the one of the email issue)

It's not a server issue because I only have this problem with this form, not with the others once I have.

Thanks a lot for your help !

here is the some part of the php form  :

```
// if all the fields have been entered correctly and there are no recaptcha errors build an email message
    if (($resp->is_valid) && (!isset($hasError))) {
    $emailTo = 'contact@website.com'; // here you must enter the email address you want the email sent to
    $subject = 'Message from: ' . $formAuthor . ' | ' . $formSubject;  // This is how the subject of the email will look like
    $body = "Email: $formEmail  \n\nSubject: $formSubject \n\nMessage: $formContent  \n\nSent by: $formAuthor";// This is the body of the email
    $headers = 'From: <'.$formEmail.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $formEmail . "\r\n" . 'Return-Path: ' . $formEmail; // Email headers

//send email
    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

// set a variable that confirms that an email has been sent
    $emailSent = true;
            }
$emailSent = true;
}
// if there are errors in captcha fields set an error variable
if (!($resp->is_valid)){
$captchaErrorMsg = true;
}
}
} ?>
```

here is the HTML :

```
<div id="singleParagraphInputs">
<div>
<label for="formAuthor">Name</label>
<input class="requiredField <?php if($authorError) { echo 'formError'; } ?>" type="text" name="formAuthor" id="formAuthor" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['formAuthor']))  echo $_POST['formAuthor'];?>" size="40" />
</div>
<div>
<label for="formEmail">Email</label>
<input class="requiredField <?php if($emailError) { echo 'formError'; } ?>" type="text" name="formEmail" id="formEmail" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['formEmail']))  echo $_POST['formEmail'];?>" size="40" />
</div>
<div>
<label for="formSubject">Subject</label>
<input type="text" name="formSubject" id="formSubject" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['formSubject']))  echo $_POST['formSubject'];?>" size="40" />
</div>
<div id="commentTxt">
<label for="formContent">Message</label>
<textarea class="requiredField <?php if($commentError) { echo 'formError'; } ?>" id="formContent" name="formContent" cols="40" rows="5"><?php if(isset($_POST['formContent'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['formContent']); } else { echo $_POST['formContent']; } } ?></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$emailTo  = 'contact@website.com';

$subject  = "Message from: " . ' <'. $formEmail .'> ' . "|" . ' <'. $formSubject .'> ';

$body = "Email: " . ' <'. $formEmail .'> ' . "\n\n Subject: " . ' <'. $formSubject .'> ' . "\n\n Message: " . ' <'. $formContent .'> ' . "\n\n Sent by: " . ' <'. $formAuthor .'> ';
// Body alternative $body = "Email: " . ' <'. $formEmail .'> ' . "\n\n" . " Subject: " . ' <'. $formSubject .'> ' . "\n\n" . "Message: " . ' <'. $formContent .'> ' . "\n\n" . "Sent by: " . ' <'. $formAuthor .'> ';

$headers  = "From: " . ' <'. $formEmail .'> ' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . ' <'. $formEmail .'> ' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: " . ' <'. $formEmail .'> ' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";

$mail     = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

if($mail) {
  // If success
}
else {
  // If fail
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Mdesdev! I tried your proposition but it's not changing the way I receive the email. I have also noticed that anything in between `<` and `>` are stripped out in $formAuthor  and $formContent but not in  $formSubject. Any idea if it's related ?

Comment: Thanks for your update. I did try it (and also the body alternative), but it didn't change the way I receive my mail : still getting the \ before the " and ' in $formSubject. and they are changed into their ASCII characters in $formAuthor and $formContent. And still anything in between < and > are stripped out in $formAuthor and $formContent. I have also updated the php code in my question maybe it will help you more. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm sorry I could not help more but check out [PHP Mail Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) maybe that's gonna help you to fix your problem.

Comment: Thansk for your reply. I noticed a new issue : when the from is submitted with a error in the captcha, the form keep in memory what was written in the field but anything after " in the `$formAuthor`  and `$formSubject` is stripped out but not in `$formContent` (it's weird because it does follow the same logic than the one of the email issue). Thanks for the link, I'm going to study it!